# Proof that area element in polar coordinates is $dA=rdr d \theta$ using $dA=(2r dr+(dr)^2) \frac{d\theta}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Please don't mark this question as duplicate, I saw other similar questions and answers didn't satisfied me.
I have task to calculate mass of figure knowing 2d density of figure using polar coordinates.
From calculus books I know, that volume element is $dA=rdr d \theta$, but suppose I don't believe that. I saw several proofs of it and they didn't satisfy me.

1)Using elementary geometry it is easy to show that area element should be equal to $dA=(2r dr+(dr)^2) \frac{d\theta}{2}$. I need it to show that area element is indeed $dA=rdr d \theta$ from $dA=(2r dr+(dr)^2) \frac{d\theta}{2}$. Usually in text-book profs it is told that we can neglect term that is proportional to  $(dr)^2$, because it has larger order of infinitesmalnes, I don't understand why it is valid to set $(dr)^2$ as zero.   I need algebraic proof of it and not justification of it. Can you pleace help me?

2)I can grasp, that I need to prove that:
$\int_0^{2\pi} \rho(\theta,r)\int_0^R (2r dr+(dr)^2) \frac{\theta}{2}=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R \rho(\theta,r) rdr d \theta $.
I know that from definition of integral we have
$\int_0^{2\pi} \rho(\theta,r)\int_0^R (2r dr+(dr)^2) \frac{\theta}{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n  \rho(\theta_i,r_i) (2r \Delta r_i+(\Delta r_i)^2) \frac{d\theta_i}{2}$, so
$\int_0^{2\pi} \rho(\theta,r)\int_0^R (2r dr+(dr)^2) \frac{\theta}{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n  \rho(\theta_i,r_i) r_i \Delta r_i d\theta+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n  \rho(\theta_i,r_i) (\Delta r_i)^2 \frac{d\theta_i}{2}$, so
$\int_0^{2\pi} \rho(\theta,r)\int_0^R (2r dr+(dr)^2) \frac{\theta}{2}=\int_0^{2\pi} \rho(\theta,r)\int_0^R r dr{\theta}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n  \rho(\theta_i,r_i) (\Delta r_i)^2 \frac{d\theta_i}{2}$

So it should be that:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n  \rho(\theta_i,r_i) (\Delta r_i)^2 \frac{d\theta_i}{2}=0$.
Why it is so? Can you please show me how to prove it algebraically?

Comment: Let's go back to basics. Let $y=x^2$, so $y+dy=(x+dx)^2$ and $dy=2x\cdot dx+dx^2$. Do you understand why we can drop the $dx^2$?

Comment: I understand, but I don't need justification of it, I need algebraic proof of it. That is I need sequence of formulas each of witch is axiom or hypothesis or is derived from them using inference rules. This sequence should end in sentence I want to be proven.

Comment: You're not going to get a fully correct proof here because this (change of variables) is really one of the most technical theorems in multivariable calculus. The best you'll find are heuristics to motivate the right formula, but an actually correct proof is very technical, and it takes quite some work to show all the approximations are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a result that may help you understand why you can drop the $(dr)^2$ term.

Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is bounded and $\mathcal{P}_n:=\Big\{[x_{k-1},x_k],t_k\Big\}_{k=1}^n$ a sequence of tagged partitions of $[a,b]$ such that $\max_{1\leq k \leq n}\Delta x_k\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Then we have $$\sum_{k=1}^nf(t_k)(\Delta x_k)^2\rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n\rightarrow \infty$$ Here is why this is true. Since $f$ is bounded, find $M$ so that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Then $$\begin{eqnarray*}\Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^nf(t_k)(\Delta x_k)^2\Bigg| & \leq&\sum_{k=1}^n|f(t_k)|(\Delta x_k)^2 \\ &\leq& M\sum_{k=1}^n(\Delta x_k)^2 \\ &\leq & M \cdot \max_{1\leq k \leq n}\Delta x_k \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n\Delta x_k \\ &=& M(b-a)\cdot \max_{1\leq k \leq n}\Delta x_k \\ &\rightarrow & 0\end{eqnarray*}$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.